# What's wrong with the syntax of this SQL command

Tags: mysql, sql

No matter how long I look at it I can't find the error.
I put it in a syntax checker online and it said the error was around the ending line.

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
emp_ID      INT             (30) NOT NULL, 
position        VARCHAR     (30) NOT NULL, 
emp_FName   VARCHAR     (30) NOT NULL,
emp_LName   VARCHAR     (30) NOT NULL, 
ohip        VARCHAR     (15) NOT NULL, 
home_Phone  INT         (15), 
start_Date  DATE, 
team_ID INT             (30) NOT NULL,  

Constraint     employee_emp_ID_PK       Primary Key (emp_ID),
Constraint     employee_team_ID_FK      Foreign Key (team_ID) 

)
```

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: You specified a foreign key without indicating the table it refers to.

Comment: @Martin You're right, [it does work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da709af), at least with the final foreign key constraint removed.  So I guess Gordon is right again ^ ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A foreign key needs to references something.  So, presumably:

```
Constraint employee_team_ID_FK Foreign Key (team_ID) references teams(team_id)
```

or something like that.

In addition, I'm not sure what you mean by `int(30)`.  This is merely the display width for the value, and because integers can have only 10 digits (well, 11 if you include a negative sign), 30 doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

For foreign key please specify reference table and its primary key.

```
  CREATE TABLE employee (
    emp_ID      INT              NOT NULL  Primary Key, 
    position    VARCHAR     (30) NOT NULL, 
    emp_FName   VARCHAR     (30) NOT NULL,
    emp_LName   VARCHAR     (30) NOT NULL, 
    ohip        VARCHAR     (15) NOT NULL, 
    home_Phone  INT          , 
    start_Date  DATE, 
    team_ID INT              NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES reftable(ID),  

     )
```